# rosdep update error

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, beagleboneblack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm installing ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04 in beaglebone black,
the processor is ARMv7,
the OS type is 32-bit.
After running "sudo rosdep init" successed, when i run "rosdep update", it shows error as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml]:
 <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> 
       (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml]:
        <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> 
(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)
ERROR: unable to process source [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml]:
        <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> 
(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml)
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
ERROR: error loading sources list:
        <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> 
(https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/indigo/distribution.yaml)>
```

And I run "which rosdep" & "rosdep --version" & "apt-cache policy python-rosdep", the result is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~$ which rosdep
/usr/bin/rosdep
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~$ rosdep --version
0.10.30
ubuntu@ubuntu-armhf:~$ apt-cache policy python-rosdep
python-rosdep:
Installed: 0.10.30-1
Candidate: 0.10.30-1
Version table:
 *** 0.10.30-1 0
500 http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros/ precise/main armhf Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Please help me do with these errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216005/rosdep-update-error/) by [lanxuedonghe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23596/lanxuedonghe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2016-05-16**:
I also have this error, anyone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error here is `Name or service not known`, which suggests that you don't have a network connection, or your DNS settings are incorrect.

Are you sure your network connection is working? Try `ping www.google.com`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2019-11-01**:
He never gets a ping Google, it's blocked in China:D

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is the network issue on your end ,not ROS.Please check out your network,or change to another network.

---

Originally posted by [melodybinbin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29509/melodybinbin/) with karma: 11 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1